# Flutter Dio Error: Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: flutter, dart, dio

Actually I was using Flutter Dio Package to pass Form Data but Unfortunately I face error like below.

Dio Error: DioErrorType.response
[log] --------------------------------------------------------
[log] {"code":"Unhandled","message":"Index was outside the bounds of the array.","data":{}}

```
Response response;
Dio dio = Dio(options);
options.headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer $apiToken'
  }
String url = (baseUrl + endPoint.url).toString();
response =
          await dio.post(url, data:FormData.fromMap(params), queryParameters: queryParams);
```

Answer (score -1):

To me, it seems like you're getting a response from the backend/API but it's just not what you're expecting, because I see three different keys: `code`, `message` and `data` (most probably these are returned from the API). Maybe the data you're sending is too large for the backend to handle? Either way, it'd be a good idea to test the API using Postman with the same input you're sending through the app.

Comment: I already tested the same in postman but works fine. But in mobile app I was facing error like so.